# How code coverage can be done of a compiled code or deployed application?

Tags: java, unit-testing, integration-testing, code-coverage

I want to know ways or tools that allow instrumentation of code that is to be deployed as a jar or similar, so that when a jar is used it can allow me recording of what underlying source code is used/accessed.
I have come across tools that allow code coverage in Java. But once the application is deployed, how to perform the same at that time? 
This will also give me a glimpse that how frequently a certain module or part of code is being used?

Comment: See [Measuring production code coverage with JaCoCo](https://carlosbecker.com/posts/production-code-coverage-jacoco/). The idea is to run jacoco as java agent alongside with your application. The output is some jacoco.exec file. Then you can transform this file to html report using jacocoant.jar or jacococli.jar

Comment: Possibly downvoted because some might think this question belongs on serverfault.com.  However, imo, regular Java developers are in our rights to ask these questions and get answers from the developer POV.

Answer (score 0):

You can try free jacoco library. Also you can check dynatrace which is pretty successful but not for free.

https://www.dynatrace.com/capabilities/business-transaction-monitoring/